# Defining getter in C#.NET, declared body not accepted

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, dictionary, getter

Consider the following code:

```
[DataContract]
class QObject {
    public QObject() { }
    [DataMember(Name = "objectindex")]
    public int ObjectIndex { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "datapoint")]
    public int DataPoint { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string Type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public int[] Data { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "parameters")]
    public string __Parameters {
        get {
            return this.__Parameters;
        }
        set {
            Parameters = new Dictionary<string,string>();
            Parameters.Add("key", "value");
        } 
    }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters;
}
```

Which seems fine by me, but when I want to compile, it gets the following error:

'QuartzService.NET.QObject.__Parameters.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

The strange thing is, that the get *has* declared a body. So, how to fix this?

Comment: `return this.__Parameters;` wouldn't that be recursive and never return?

Comment: It's also suspicious that you don't use `value` in the setter, and also that you've got a public field.

Comment: No idea where your error comes from, but your getter is infinitely recursive, and your setter ignores the `value`, and finally the backing field is public.

Comment: The issue is already solved. I was looking at an old error. Visual Studio doesn't compile-on-save (as does Flex, which I am using simultaneously). Not using 'value' is because it is all in debugging-and-figuring-out-how-it-works. The infinite loop I didn't see. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a getter returns  **another**  variable not itself . Maybe you want to return something from parameters. Furthermore your setter always creates a **new** dictionary and adds the same thing into it. What are you trying to do?

try something like this

```
        public string __Parameters
    {
        get { return this.recreate(); } 
        set
        {
            Parameters = parse(value));
        }
    }     

    public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters;
```

where the parse funciton takes in a string, breaks it and stores it into the dictionary. and the recreate function uses the dictionary to recreate the string.

also Do this:

```
 public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters = new Dictionary<String,String>();
```

so that you dont accidentally get null pointers and since you only need one dictionary in my opinion. (Dont forget to clear it though  when you parse a new String ).

Comment: I want to parse the __Parameters when they get set from the DataContract.

Comment: so you will recieve a string, you want to break them into key value pairs and then store them?  And when some one calls a getter , you want to return the original string?

Answer (score 4):

Have you noticed the infinite loop in getter

```
 public string __Parameters {
    get {
        return this.__Parameters;
    }
 .........
```

Answer (score 0):

the getter you defined well introduce a recursive call.

```
public string __Parameters {
    get {
        return this.__Parameters;
    }
}
```

try to change this.__Parameters; by

```
private string _parameters 
public string __Parameters {
    get {
        return this._parameters;
    }
}
```